# Is there a general way to delete an entire function over multiple lines using sed?

Tags: c, regex, sed

Im trying to use the following command to delete a main function, however im getting stuck because I'm left with a "}" and a new line after.

Here is what I have so far:

```
sed -E '/int main/,/return 0\;/ d' program.c
```

I can't end the matching string with } because inside this main function, there is already a set of closing brackets.

Comment: But the brace that closes the function is at the beginning of the line, no?

Comment: In the general case, no; you need a full-fledged C parser to be really sure where the function definitions are in a file of C code.

Comment: Yes, I know, but a usual C file has the closing brace of a function in the first column. At least that's how I format my code. And that would be a better heuristic than relying on `return 0` being the last line in a function, in my opinion.

Comment: This task is not suitable for `sed` in general case. But if your main function ends with a line consisting of a single `}` and is properly indented (that is, there is no another line inside main satisfying this condition) then something like that might work for you: `sed '/int main[[:space:]]*(/,/^}$/d'`

Comment: What do you **_really_** want to achieve? Depending on the real issue there will be some answer most probably.